# Executing a Shell Script on Remote Server :: Gives sqlplus: command not found

Tags: linux, shell

I have two servers **Server A** which has a shell script - 'Process_Backup.sh'.

I executed this script on server A - './Process_Backup.sh' and it executed fine. Basically this script connects to my oracle database on Server A and executes a procedure.

What I need to do is execute the script 'Process_Backup.sh' on server A from a different **Server B**.

I tried following command from **Server B**

```
ssh test@server1.xxx.com "cd Scripts/Shell; ./Process_Backup.sh"
```

But I am getting following error-

```
line 49: sqlplus: command not found
```

I have all the software installed on server A so not sure why am I getting this error. I am new to linux environment. I have gone through most of the question posted here but mine seems to be a different case.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I didn't understand if I'm connecting to server A, will the script not execute on server A ? why do we need to install oracle client on server B. can you point me to some thing I can read on.. my basics might not be clear yet.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question. I thought you were trying to run `./Process_Backup.sh` on B. I’ll remove my first comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: When invoking a command via `ssh`, it doesn't source the login's rc scripts such as `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` for `bash` shells, or `.login` and `.cshrc` for `csh` shells or `.profile` for `sh` and `dash` shells. Either source them as part of the command you pass or build the environment variables in `.Process_Backup.sh`, or source `oraenv` as answered by @RalFriedl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle installs a file `oraenv` that sets some environment variables including the PATH where commands like `sqlplus` are. That file is included when you start your login shell, the commands to do that were probably created by the installer.

Use

```
ssh test@server1.xxx.com "source /path/to/oraenv; cd Scripts/Shell; ./Process_Backup.sh"
```

The file `oraenv` is probably somewhere below `/usr/local`.

Comment: above solution works, however in my script I wasn't doing bash so was not able to look to bash profile